# Expose docker port based on environment variable in compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am using docker compose to set up application environments. There are two distinct environments, test and production.

In a test environment, I need to expose additional ports (for debugging). These ports should remain closed in a production environment.

I would also like to use the same image and `docker-compose.yml` file. Using the same image is no problem but I am struggeling with the compose file. In it, I would like to open or close a port based on an environment variable.

The current setup is pretty much the standard, like this:

```yaml
# ...
  ports:
    - "8080:8080" # HTTP Server port
    - "9301:9301" # debug port
# ...
```

In this example, both ports are always exposed. Is it possible to expose the port `9301` only if a certain environment variable, say `EXPOSE_DEBUG`, is set?

Answer (score 6):

You can use [profiles](https://docs.docker.com/compose/profiles/) or a second compose file.

```yaml
services:
  app-prod:
    &app
    image: busybox
    profiles:
      - production
    ports:
      - 8080:8080

  app-dev:
    <<: *app
    profiles:
      - development
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 9090:9090
```

Then you can use the below command or an [environment variable](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/#compose_profiles) to set the profile, `COMPOSE_PROFILES`.

```
docker compose --profile <profile-name> up
```

---

Alternatively, you can use a second compose file and override the ports.

```yaml
# compose.yaml
services:
  app:
    image: busybox
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

```yaml
# compose.dev.yaml
services:
  app:
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 9090:9090
```

Then you can use the file after the main file to *patch* it:

```
docker compose -f compose.yaml -f compose.dev.yaml up
```

The file(s) to use can also be controls with an [environment variable](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/#compose_file), `COMPOSE_FILE`.

If you name the file `compose.override.yaml`, docker will [automatically](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#understanding-multiple-compose-files) use it, so you don't have to point to it with the -f flag. Be careful that you don't add this file to your production system, if you choose to do this.

---

You could also bind the debug port to the loopback interface (127.0.0.1) so that you can only access it locally.

```yaml
ports:
  - 8080:8080 
  - 127.0.0.1:9090:9090
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I usually use in my projects is to make a bash script that writes the `docker-compose.yml` based on the value of the environment variable. But you could write it with any other programming language as well.

Answer (score 0):

Conditional statements (`if else`) are not supported in docker compose.

1. Use additional software like jinja-compose adding Jinja2 logic to docker-compose
2. Use just two different files (dc-dev.yml and dc-prod.yml) and give them as arg (`docker compose -f`)
3. Generate `docker-compose.yml` programmatically by yourself
4. Use profiles (Was to slow, see answer of the fool)

To just maintain dev/prod environments in my opinion solution 2 is the most efficient in terms of effort.

**To follow your approach:**

You can set port mapping by envs like:

`.env`-File or add them in `docker compose up -e` command

```
PORT1="8080:8080"
PORT2="9301:9301"
```

`docker-compse.yml`

```
services:
  container1:
    ports:
      - ${PORT1}
      - ${PORT2}
```

But afaik there is no way to omit one of them